# is it possible to make an on click in an on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

Is it possible to do an on click in an click like this:

```
$(game.imageContainer).on('click', function(event) {
    var matchingClasses = true;
    $(game.differenceClass).on('click', function(event) {
        var matchingClasses = false;
    });

    if(matchingClasses){
        playwrong();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**
What i'm trying to accomplish is the following:
I have a layer(game.imageContainer) with small div's on top(game.differenceClass). If game.imageContainer is clicked I need to know if game.differenceClass is clicked as wel. If it is it should not playwrong().

Comment: Yes but I think that does something you're not intending to do.  instead you should separate the on click bindings and then use `$(game.differenceClass).trigger("click")` in the imageContainer's click

Comment: See my updatet answer

Comment: Do you need to do something when imageContainer is clicked?  from your update it seems like you only need to call playwrong when difference class is clicked

Comment: or is it possible difference won't be inside imagecontainer

Comment: if as wel the imagecontainer as the differenceclass is clicked then it should not playwrong(). if only the imagecontainer is clicked it should playwrong()

Comment: can you post your html for these classes as well? is imageContainer the parent element?

Comment: @user3398922 You should update question with all relevant code and expected behaviour, this was really unclear question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: following your new comment:

> if as wel the imagecontainer as the differenceclass is clicked then it
>   should not playwrong(). if only the imagecontainer is clicked it
>   should playwrong()

```
$(game.imageContainer).on('click', function (event) {
    if(event.target !== this) return;
    playwrong();
});
```

***Old answer***

So delegate event instead using relevant class to discard selector, if `game.differenceClass` is a string:

```
$(game.imageContainer).on('click', '*:not('+game.differenceClass+')', playwrong);
```

or using object:

```
$(game.imageContainer).on('click', function (event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest(game.differenceClass).length) return;
  playwrong();
});
```

Comment: This is exaclty what I needed. I did not now it was possible to write it this way.